# Add onClick from Intention dialog (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, onclick

I am new in Android Studio, but experienced in Visual.
When I put a control , say a button, in the design window and press double click on it, then Visual Studio auto generates onClick action.

I can see the same in Android Studio - called Intention Dialog.
There is onClick suggestion, but it doesn not work for me..

[image: Pls see the pic.]

I touch the button and then go to java text, then press Alt-Enter and the only one element is available: Insert App indexing API code. 
[image: see the pic..]

I need onClick..

Pls, help me to understand its logics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Define an OnClickListener for your view

[image: Define an OnClickListener for your view]

**Step 2:** Press **Alt + Enter** to create onClick handler

[image: Press Alt + Enter to create onClick handler]

**Step 3:** Choose target Activity to create your onClick method

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: what do you think is that guy following your way?

Comment: Yeah but there's a little difference. In the way i show you don't need to write on click method yourself. Android Studio will automatically generate for you.

Comment: I don't understand his actions - he says I drag the button and move it into the Activity and then he just presses some magic keys and gets the callback code.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you not use generated code.
To get the onCLick button, you could do this:

```
private Button yourButton;
.
.
.

yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.(THE ID YOU PUT ON YOUR XML BUTTON));
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // YOUR ACTIONS
  }
});
```

Comment: I know I can do it, but I want to know how to use the intentions dialog

Comment: Why do you "strongly" suggest this? Loads of template code is created automagically.